# How to convert Text to Binary (and Reverse) in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, serialization, boost, c++17

Okay, this will be a very *beginner* question, Though I can´t seem to find a *good* resource on this topic.

What I want is simple. take a string (or char*) and convert it to a binary file that I can store somewhere on my system. 
Then, *at a later date*, I want to be able to read that binary file and convert it back to a string (or char*).

Now... 
Whenever I search for this I often get to the concept of *Serialisation*, which is *basically* what I want.

There´s a problem though, most often "Boost-Serialisation" is recommended. Which (**IMO**) is quite heavy for just converting simple text to binary and converting simple binary to text. (*ok, I know it isn´t THAT easy, but you get the idea*)

There has *got* to be an easier way to handle this. I hope you can help me find it. :D

Thank you very much in advance for your answers.

Comment: When you say binary file, do you mean you want the file to have a string made up of one and zero characters? Because the term "binary file" is a technical term that refers to any kind of file that you can't open up with a text editor.

Comment: @Noah You can definitely open it with text editor, and it may even have a readable content. I honestly cannot think of any difference between a file written in binary mode or text mode, after they are saved you cannot distinguish what mode was used.

Comment: That _"easier way"_ is called a Database System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to convert Text to Binary (and Reverse)

There's nothing to do. Text is *already* data, and the in-memory presentation of all data in any modern computer is always binary.

You need to know what you mean. If you just mean "write it to a file" (in any representation), then just do that:

```
std::string my_text;
std::ofstream ofs("myfile.bin", std::ios::binary);
ofs.write(my_text.data(), my_text.size());
```

If you need some **specific** representation (different character sets, encodings or even (archive) file formats) you might need to do that conversion.

Oh, lest I forget, to read-back:

```
std::ifstream ifs("myfile.bin", std::ios::binary);
std::string my_text(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});
```

Comment: Hello sehe. Could you please provide some feedback on [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/257710/c-implementation-of-depth-first-search) question?

Comment: @a_sid Scanning the answers there I think you've got all the feedback you could wish for :)

Comment: @a_sid And of course, couldn't leave well enough alone https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/260560/4569

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use bit manipulation tricks. C and C++ both have operators that allow you to run integer values through logic gates. So for example:

```
x = 3 & 1 ;
```

Will set x to 1 because when you do an AND operation you're taking every bit from the left side of the & and the corresponding bit from the right side of the & and putting them through an [And operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate).

You can also do bit shifting. Where you shift the bits over by some number. For example:

```
y = 1 << 2;
```

Will shift all the bits in the integer 1 over by two, and the new rightmost bits will be set to zero.

So the way to do this is: for every byte in the string, do an AND operation with 128 and then if the value from that is zero then that means the left-most bit is zero (and you print "0"), if not then the value is one (so you print "1"). Then shift it to the left by one and do the operation again. Do that eight times and you've converted one byte to binary.

Comment: What part of what question is being answered here? Did you interpret the question to mean "how to obfuscate my text"?

Comment: No, I'm talking about how to take a string of characters, and make another string of characters that contains the binary representation of it.

Comment: There are many binary representations of character data. Why pick a particularly inefficient one? I think you accidentally answered "how to treat text as a number sequence and then print these numbers in base-2 number system". I know that "base-2 numbers" are often dubbed "binary numbers" but "binary data" most definitely does **not** refer to that. _[Also, you have a catch-22 problem, because now you've converted your number sequence to text (a string of 0s and 1s). Uhm. How are you going to convert that text to binary?]_

Comment: I think you don't understand. EVERYTHING in the computer is already in binary. I'm pretty sure OP wants something that can convert a piece of text to a string containing ones and zeros.

Comment: Hah. I think you must not have read my answer (posted a hour or so before your comment) then :) That's precisely the point I start out with. You may be right, but I trust my experience reading questions on this site. No biggie. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ofstream/ifstream. They work similar to cout/cin except it reads and writes files instead of the console.  Maybe this link is helpful: https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/